# How to detect when horizontal swipe starts UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITable with a button in each cell.

When you touchdown on the button, something happens.

When you swipe left on the cell, the nav controller pushes to another view.

The problem is that sometimes these two things overlap.

The touchdown even waits for probably half a second before it registers a touch down.

This is enough time for it to register while the user is in mid swipe sometimes.

I want to make it so that if the user is in mid swipe (the user's finger velocity is greater than a certain amount possibly?) then I can set the button to be unclickable.

But I don't know how to detect the touch's velocity. I would think with a combination of a timer and a variable that stores the old touch's location? But I also can't use a Pan gesture recognizer because it overrides the scroll feature on the table and the swipe right feature on the view controller.

Comment: How important is it that the button recognizes touch down as opposed to touch up? Are you using a tap gesture recognizer or control states?

Comment: I'm using control states I believe. And it is crucial that it is on touch down - The button changes size once the touch down even is called

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
[yourButton setExclusiveTouch:YES];
```

to avoid unwanted touch events. Try it when initialize `yourButton`

Answer (score 0):

If you set delaysTouchesBegan to YES on the gesture recognizer then it won't send touches to the view until the swipe gesture fails. That should stop the touch down happening at the same time as the swipe.

Comment: I think his problem is the UIControl's state is changing on a swipe, not the other way around (gesture being recognized on a control state changed)

Comment: Your comment implies you misunderstood what this code would do. I would expect the control state to not change on swipe with this change as it would stop the control receiving touch events until swipe recognition had failed. Did you try setting delaysTouchesBegan?